# Excel 2010 Macro does not find value

Tags: excel-2010, return-value

I have a macro that searches but does not find the “7”  (If Right(pair, 2) = 7 Then). The thing is when I change the number to 11 or 12 etc. (any two digits) and the findXX in the code, it works fine. Does anyone know what’s occurring and what is the exact change I need to do.

Option Explicit

Sub DivideSomeStuff()

```
Dim pair As Range, accumulator As Range
Dim findSeven As Double
Dim remainder As Long

For Each pair In Range("B30, F30, J30")
    If Right(pair, 2) = 7 Then
        If pair.Offset(0, 2) <= 12 Then
            remainder = 0
        Else
            remainder = pair.Offset(0, 2) Mod 10
        End If

        findSeven = (pair.Offset(0, 2) - remainder) / 10

        For Each accumulator In Range("A36, D36, G36, J36, M36, A40, D40, G40, J40, M40")
            If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) = Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-") - 1)) Then
                accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + remainder
            End If
            accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value +  findSeven
        Next accumulator
    End If
Next pair
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi and welcome. To get a better change of getting an answer, I suggest you edit your title and tags to let the readers know which software this macro is for. From the code I guess it can be either excel or open|libreOffice calc. Theire are specific tags for all of them

Answer (score 0):

Change it from ...

```
Right(pair, 2) = 7
```

... to ...

```
Right(pair, 1) = 7
```

You’re currently getting the 2 right values when 7 is a single character.

You may need to put quotes around the 7 too, see if works without them though.

Comment: That did it, Thank-you so much.

Comment: @NANCYSKYES please flag is as the the answer then . Glad I could help.